# How do I escape special characters in a Java regex that will be available only at run time

Tags: java, regex

Pattern.quote("/:*?"<>|#") does not seem to work when \ and " are part of the string.

The code will be receiving a sting of allowed special characters at run time, for e.g., `"\/:*?"<>|#"` so here `\` and `"` need to be escaped.

What my code is required to do: Replace all characters other than alphanumeric and the allowed special characters with a default character say `~`

What I have written so far:

```
String replacer = "~"; 

String fileName = path.replaceAll("[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}^\\p{IsDigit}\\:*?\"<>|#~]", replacer);
```

This works. But how do I generalize the solution given that the allowed special characters will only be known at run time. 
I tried appending `\\` to every allowed special character but `\` and `"` throw errors in that case.

Comment: Pattern.quote("/:*?"<>|#") does not seem to work when \ and " are part of the string.

Comment: `\ ` and `"` are both special characters that need to be escaped with a backslash in any string. Nothing to do with regex.